# Using AND between two corresponding elements of Array and OR between them in Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Pardon me if I'm being dumb, been coding for 30 hours straight**

**Final Output Required:**

> SELECT * FROM `cities_extended` WHERE (`state_code` = 'MO' AND
>   `county`= 'GREENE') OR (`state_code` = 'NY' AND `county` = 'GREENE')

**My Try:**
I have this query (written for testing), I wrote the code for it in codeigniter but I've failed to properly convert it into codeigniter's Active Record. I'm aware of where_in and or_where_in functions of codeigniter. I tried the following code:

```
// some code 
$counties = $query->result_array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($counties); $i++)
{
   $this->db->or_where('county', $counties[$i]['county']);
   $this->db->where('state_code', $counties[$i]['state_code']);
}
   $this->db->select('zip');
   $zips_query = $this->db->get('cities_extended');
   return $this->db->last_query();
 // some code
```

This gives the following output:

```
"SELECT `zip` FROM `cities_extended` WHERE `county` = 'Laclede' AND `state_code` = 'MO' OR `county` = 'Greene' AND `state_code` = 'MO' OR `county` = 'Webster' AND `state_code` = 'MO'"
```

**Crux:** HOW DO I PUT ( county ='HELP' **AND** state_code = 'ME' ) **OR** ( county= 'WILL' **AND** state_code ='YOU') using **Codeigniter's Active Record**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like in the below code

```
$this -> db -> select('*') -> from ('cities_extended') -> where("(state_code = 'MO' AND county= 'GREENE')") -> or_where("(state_code = 'NY' AND county = 'GREENE')");

$result = $this -> db -> get();
```

**Edit: Please do the below one**

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($counties); $i++)
{
   $this->db->or_where("'county' = '".$counties[$i]['county']."' AND 'state_code' = '".$counties[$i]['state_code."']");
}
```

Comment: he needs to make it by looping where he has county and state. It is not singly 2 county and 2 states. It would be more than 2.

Comment: naf4me is right. I changed the loop body with a little bit of hint from your answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did it this way. I got hint from Arun's answer. Still had to do change a bit. I changed the loop body as follows:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($counties); $i++)
    $this->db->or_where("( state_code = '".$counties[$i]['state_code']. "' AND county = '".$counties[$i]['county']."' )");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('cities_extended');
$this->db->where("state_code",  'MO');
$this->db->where('county','GREENE') 
$this->db->or_where("state_code",'NY');
$result = $this->db->get();
```